# Someone hacked my Google account.What now?

Tags: google-accounts

I can't get into my Google account. My boyfriend got into my account and changed all my phone numbers plus changed my recovery email/phone number. Pictures of my kids birthday events and their birth was saved to that account. My contacts plus a lot more.

Please help, how can I recover my account?

Comment: This is a classic example of needing to backup your critical data to more than just one location i.e. Google Drive. You will need to follow this instructions listed here: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6294825?hl=en and if it works and you get your access & your data is still there, be sure to lock down gmail with more security functionality so this doesn't happen, don't tell anyone any of your login credentials, don't answer security question with answers personal friends would know, & do a ton more homework of the subject of protecting your social media data, email accounts, etc.

Comment: This is really an answer, though I don't expect it would be highly up-voted.  I notice you said "boyfriend".  Since that term indicates that you are on still on speaking terms with him, talk to him.  Figure out why he did this.  Instruct him to return control to you right away.  If he insists of acting like a thief, then it's time to start re-phrasing what you call him, into "ex-boyfriend".

Comment: Sounds like you're 12 yrs old, tell your parents. If you're an adult seek law enforcement if you can prove it. Also contact Google

Comment: @JeremyThompson If the author is younger then 13 then that's a problem (it means their profile will be deleted) you have to be 13+ to use SE

Comment: Its extremely unlikely a 13yo would have a child of their own...

Answer (score 1):

If you know your Gmail address, you can attempt go through the [Google account recovery](https://accounts.google.com/signin/recovery) process.

Otherwise, Google provides this [Troubleshooting Page](https://support.google.com/accounts/troubleshooter/2402620?visit_id=1-636403896613894345-4078307879&p=ar_other_problems_username&rd=1). From the section on *"You think someone else is using your account"*:

> ### You can't sign in to your account
>
> For help getting back in to your account:
>
> 1. Go to the [Account support page](https://accounts.google.com/signin/recovery).
> 2. Follow the instructions. You'll be asked some questions to confirm it's your account. Answer as best you can.
> 3. Reset your password. Choose a strong password that you haven't already used with this account. [Learn how to create a strong password.](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/32040)